# Is there a way to get the number of available audio devices using AudioToolBox.h?

Tags: objective-c, macos, objective-c++

I'm trying to make my own audio recorder using Objective-C. It's my first time making one and I'm kind of curious, is there a way to get the number of audio devices using AudioToolBox.h?

Answer (score 0):

For UKSoundFileRecorder I did AudioObjectGetPropertyData[Size] with { kAudioHardwarePropertyDevices, kAudioObjectPropertyScopeGlobal, kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster }. Then looked which devices can get input.

The code is here in case you wanna peek: https://github.com/uliwitness/UKSoundFileRecorder